# Print invoice format is not proper in customer dashboard Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Tags: css, invoice, magento-1.9.2.1, format, create-invoice

[image: invoice]
I am getting below format of invoice , when customer Print there invoice form there Dashboard.

**Which files are responsible for the same.**

I replaced sales folder under `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales` with fresh sales folder.

still format is same

NOTE: There is no `sales` folder in theme template folder.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Saurabh Ranjan, I am facing the same issue. Did you find anything regarding this?

Comment: Hello @vedu sir, the problem is solved , as i found that core file is altered by some developer who worked on it previously , what i did is replaced all core file related to invoice  with fresh  files and then extended those file in local pool , make changes as desired